# Create a CSV file from an XML file?

Tags: xml, vb.net, csv

This code will indeed create an Excel .csv file, but it's not a true CSV. All that will be contained in it is some gobbledygook which VB creates from `dgvStats.Rows.ToString`. I'm guessing that some kind of a `For...Each` is needed here, but I can't see how I would work that out.

Thanks for your help!

```
Private Sub btnCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
    Dim StatsData As XElement = XElement.Load("Basketball.xml")
    Dim query = From p In StatsData.Descendants("player")
    Let name = p.<name>.Value
    Let team = p.<team>.Value
    Let points = CInt(p.<points>.Value)
    Let steals = CInt(p.<steals>.Value)
    Order By points Descending
    Select name, team, points, steals

    Dim sw As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.CreateText("Basketball.csv")
    sw.WriteLine(dgvStats.Rows.ToString)
    sw.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Basketball.csv created in bin\Debug folder. " &
                    "Use Windows Explorer to find it.")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this what you're after?

```
For Each x In query
    sw.WriteLine(String.Format("""{0}"", ""{1}"", {2}, {3}", x.name, x.team, x.points, x.stats)
Next
```

Comment: Very much, yes. Let me give that a try.

Comment: Cool! Yes, that works great, although it leaves the quotation format around the String objects, which makes the .txt file a bit harder to use. Is there another way to format that?

Comment: Putting the `"` around the strings covers the case where a `,` appears within the string. Can you tell me why it makes the text file harder to use?

Answer (score 0):

I also found that this code works.

P.S. The SO code formatting doesn't seem to be working properly here. Did I enter the code wrong?

```
Private Sub btnCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
    'Create a new query which puts the XML data in CSV format. 
    'The last Let statement makes the change. This String is then Selected.
    Dim StatsData As XElement = XElement.Load("Basketball.xml")
    Dim queryCreate = From p In StatsData.Descendants("player")
    Let name = p.<name>.Value
    Let team = p.<team>.Value
    Let points = CInt(p.<points>.Value)
    Let steals = CInt(p.<steals>.Value)
    Let outputLine = CStr(name & "," & team & "," & points & "," & steals)
    Order By points Descending
    Select outputLine

    'Make sure that .txt file does not already exist, or else delete it
    'See CheckForExistingFile Sub definition below.
    CheckForExistingFile("Basketball.txt")

    'Write CSV file
    IO.File.WriteAllLines("Basketball.txt", queryCreate)
    MessageBox.Show("Basketball.txt CSV file has been created in bin\Debug. " &
                    "Close the program and hit Refresh in Solution Explorer " &
                    "to see it. Make sure that Show All Files is selected.")
End Sub

Private Sub CheckForExistingFile(file As String)
    'Check whether file has been created previously. If so, delete it.
    If IO.File.Exists(file) Then
        IO.File.Delete(file)
    End If
End Sub
```